# SQL Like statement: Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, exception, ado.net

I have a text box which allows a user to search for content on our site, here is the c# code to handle was is passed in:

```
string search = Server.HTMLDecode(userEnteredSearchText);
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT data FROM database WHERE (Title LIKE @search) " 
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("search", String.Format("%{0}%", search)));
```

I've never seen this error before:

> Cannot convert a char value to money...

but it is going off if the user enters empty spaces. I debugged through it and it seems like what could be causing it is that if search = "", then the param would be %%? It seems that sometimes if a user enters enough spaces (i.e. search is "        "), then the page does not crash? But I'm not exactly sure what the problem is.

UPDATE:
Not sure exactly what the issue with this is but I fixed it by using a RequiredFieldValidator for the textbox.

Comment: Where if your `FROM` part in your query?

Comment: Sorry about that, copy paste error. Just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kevin, Why not check if the user is entering "" ? Then if the user is entering "" give them an error to fix their input before its sent to the database.

Comment: I actually just did that. I put in a RequiredFieldValidator that won't fire the search command if nothing is entered. Works great!

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `money` value to `string`. Try like this;

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT CAST(Result AS VARCHAR(MAX)) WHERE (Keyword LIKE @search) "
```

Comment: I don't see where the money value is coming from? If a user types into the search bar "hello" for example, then my params would be %hello%, and the query would be "SELECT data FROM database WHERE (%hello% LIKE @search). This works fine. It's just that when it is a empty text the user passes in that causes the problem.